# Responsive lightbox mix images

Tags: javascript, lightbox

I am currently use on my website a responsive lightbox https://github.com/duncanmcdougall/Responsive-Lightbox

As i have more than 1 gallery, I am having problem because the gallery are mixed together as you can see here: http://www.ibikemontaione.com/it/dove-dormire-toscana.html

I set 2 different functions (following instructions) for both blocks but it doesn't work:

```
$('.gallerypiedicosta a').lightbox(); 
$('.galleryborgolacasaccia a').lightbox();
```

Does anyone can help me?

Thank you so much in advance!

Filippo

Comment: Please post your HTML code.

Answer (score -1):

this is the html code:

```
<div class="group1">

<div class="indirizzostruttura">
<div class="nomestruttura">Piè di Costa</div>
<div class="contattistruttura">Via Santo Stefano, 13/15 <br />Montaione<br />email: info@piedicosta.com<br />website: <a title="appartamenti vacanze in Toscana" href="http://www.piedicosta.com/it" target="_blank">www.piedicosta.com</a></div>
</div>

<div class="fotogallerystrutturericettive">

<div class="fotostruttura1 gallerypiedicosta">
<a href="images/strutturericettive/piedicosta/piedicosta-foto1X.jpg" title="Piè di Costa"><img src="images/strutturericettive/piedicosta/piedicosta-foto1.jpg" alt="Piè di Costa" /></a>
</div>


<div class="fotostruttura2 gallerypiedicosta">
<a href="images/strutturericettive/piedicosta/piedicosta-foto2X.jpg" title="Piè di Costa"><img src="images/strutturericettive/piedicosta/piedicosta-foto2.jpg" alt="Piè di Costa" /></a>
<a href="images/strutturericettive/piedicosta/piedicosta-foto4X.jpg" title="Piè di Costa"><img src="images/strutturericettive/piedicosta/piedicosta-foto4.jpg" alt="Piè di Costa" /></a>
<a href="images/strutturericettive/piedicosta/piedicosta-foto3X.jpg" title="Piè di Costa"><img src="images/strutturericettive/piedicosta/piedicosta-foto3.jpg" alt="Piè di Costa" /></a>
</div>

</div><

</div>


<div class="group1">

<div class="indirizzostruttura">
<div class="nomestruttura">Borgo La Casaccia</div>
<div class="contattistruttura">Via delle Rocche, 39<br />Montaione<br />email: info@borgolacasaccia.it<br />website: <a href="http://www.borgolacasaccia.it" target="_blank">www.borgolacasaccia.it</a></div>
</div><!-- Fine Indirizzo 1 -->

<div class="fotogallerystrutturericettive">

<div class="fotostruttura1 galleryborgolacasaccia">
<a href="images/strutturericettive/borgolacasaccia/borgolacasaccia-foto1X.jpg" title="Borgo La Casaccia"><img src="images/strutturericettive/borgolacasaccia/borgolacasaccia-foto1.jpg" alt="Borgo La Casaccia" /></a>
</div>


<div class="fotostruttura2 galleryborgolacasaccia">
<a href="images/strutturericettive/borgolacasaccia/borgolacasaccia-foto2X.jpg" title="Borgo La Casaccia"><img src="images/strutturericettive/borgolacasaccia/borgolacasaccia-foto2.jpg" alt="Borgo La Casaccia" /></a>
<a href="images/strutturericettive/borgolacasaccia/borgolacasaccia-foto4X.jpg" title="Borgo La Casaccia"><img src="images/strutturericettive/borgolacasaccia/borgolacasaccia-foto4.jpg" alt="Borgo La Casaccia" /></a>
<a href="images/strutturericettive/borgolacasaccia/borgolacasaccia-foto3X.jpg" title="Borgo La Casaccia"><img src="images/strutturericettive/borgolacasaccia/borgolacasaccia-foto3.jpg" alt="Borgo La Casaccia" /></a>
</div>

</div>

</div>
```

Comment: edit your original question with this code, this is not a forum :)